# Conditional Test (!="") inside value-of select

Tags: xslt

Context: I am iterating a variable list ($tagList) which is effectively a fixed list (cannot be avoided).  Within this nodeset initialising a variable 'attribute' which is then used in dynamic xpath (xalan:evaluate).  I need to include an additional conditional check to only map specific elements that are !="" (for example the **pos** element in the vTag list).  Not clear how I can combine the current xalan:evaluate(concat(.....)) function with the !="" check.

XSL snippet as follows (please disregard the 'cobbled' CDATA blocks, this is required to generate the 'fixed-position' text format required by third-party consumer).

```
<xsl:variable name="tagList">
  <vtag name="Group0100" key="name"></vtag>
  <vtag name="Group0200" key="age"></vtag>
  <vtag name="Group0300" key="dept"></vtag>
  <vtag name="Group0400" key="pos"></vtag>              
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="Extract">
 <xsl:variable name="ExtractView" select="."/>
 <xsl:for-each select="xalan:nodeset($tagList)/vtag">
   <xsl:variable name="ExtractViewTemp" select="$ExtractView"/>
   <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="./@key"/>
     <xsl:text><![CDATA[<Record type="insert">]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$br" />
    <xsl:text>  <![CDATA[<Column name="term_group_name">]]></xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="xalan:evaluate(concat('$ExtractViewTemp/', $attribute))"/><![CDATA[</Column>]]><xsl:value-of select="$br" />
```

Comment: All your `vtag` elements are empty, i.e. don't have any child nodes. So `<vtag name="Group0400" key="pos"></vtag>` looks empty to me. As for the check, I would try `<xsl:value-of select="$ExtractView/*[local-name() = $attribute][. != '']"/>`.

Comment: Apologies explanation isn't that clear.  The vtag elements are intended to be empty, I am using this array simply to iterate over to construct the output manually (using the dynamic xpath) where the @key matches the element to match (there is heavy manipulation/restructure of the input XML).  So the vtag aspect is already working correctly as expected.  The filter you have suggested above should do the trick, in process of testing and I'll advise the outcome.